# How to calculate the number of states of a 7-segment LCD?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

A 7-segment LCD display can display a number of 128 states.
The following image shows the 16x8-grid with all the possible states:

[image]

How can you calculate the number of states?

Answer (score 1):

There are $7$ segments and so the number is $2^7=128$.

Comment: Great! Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The combinations of segments can be calculated with the binomial coefficient:

$$
_nC_k=\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
I came across this problem evaluating the different number of segments lightened:

> *No segment* $= 1$
>   *One segment* $= \binom 71 = \frac{7!}{1!(6)!} = 7$
>   *Two segments* $= \binom 72 = \frac{7!}{2!(5)!} = 21$
>   *Three segments* $= \binom 73 = \frac{7!}{3!(4)!} = 35$
>   *Four segments* $= \binom 74 = \frac{7!}{4!(3)!} = 35$
>   *Five segments* $= \binom 75 = \frac{7!}{5!(2)!} = 21$
>   *Six segments* $= \binom 76 = \frac{7!}{6!(1)!} = 7$
>   *Seven segments* $= 1$
>
> Number of states = 1+7+21+35+35+21+7+1 = **128**

Comment: A hint: $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$. In your case $\sum_{k=0}^7 {7 \choose k}=2^7=128$

Comment: Awesome @callculus!

Comment: Your are welcome. The equation can be derived from the binomial theorem.